# Atlassian jira. Нужно ли хранить папку с плагином в проде?

Tags: jira

Всем привет. У меня есть проблема с разработкой плагина по jira. Скачал себе локально sdk, сделал плагин,потом загрузил плагин на прод .jar через манагер плагинов, но web-resources не подгружаются ни css, ни js. Локально на :2990  js и css норм подгружается. Нужно ли держать всю папку с плагином рядом с продом? И может кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? Спасибо.

Comment: Я нашел решение в телеге у знакомых. Sdk была версии 7х, а Enterprize 8x поэтому вебресурсы не подгружались, хотя сам плагин загружлся как надо и жира не ругалась. Я еще не видел такой ужасной доки как у атлассиан.